# Where are the CD label graphics and labels for the current release?

Tags: live-cd, cd

Did Ubuntu provide any CD label pics for the current release? I've looked all around in the livecd iso directories.

I want to lightscribe something, for this Live CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DIYMarketing#Current_DIYMarketing_content:) is a link to the official images on the Ubuntu wiki.